# SFMC Connector or Data Extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, sfmc-business-unit

What are the benefits of using the SFMC Connector over a Data Extension if my company doesn't want to house B2C contacts (they have B2C and B2B contacts) within Salesforce CRM and only SFMC?

Comment: This is indeed a very broad question, and basically no context allowing us to understand your scenario. There are multiple consequences of using SFMC as system of record for contacts and consents in a multi-cloud environment. Your will probably be best off teaming up with a Salesforce Architect, who can evaluate your setup and data, and provide more in-depth analysis and recommendation.

Answer (score 2):

This is a broad question and there is no 100% right or wrong answer here. I wouldn't be surprised if this gets closed.

What can be generalized:

If you already have a system storing personal data in Sales Cloud, and you now start a second isolated one, in which you also store personal data, but which you do not connect -

At some point you might notice that processes between the two systems *HAVE* a connection, just from a factual perspective. The same people call service that receive your newsletter.

Consider that newsletter recipients call service and want them to unsubscribe / delete etc., or want to change their email address.

By creating two data silos that do not talk to each other you are basically assuming this will never happen / that it doesnt matter that these things get super complicated. At some point - some people might disagree.

If it's already done though - once the realization comes that this should be changed, getting this cleaned out later when two systems are up and running in production, it is a preventable mess.